# Update custom table section header view content real-time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with a custom `tableView` header, i.e. I can't update table section content in real time.

Here is the sample code which demonstrates my problem:

```
//SomeViewController.swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if let infoHeaderView = InfoHeaderView.viewFromNib as? InfoHeaderView {
       infoHeaderView.update(with: someContent)
       updateMethod = { newContent in
                infoHeaderView.update(with: newContent)
            }
    }
}
...
updateMethod(someContent)
...


//InfoHeaderView.swift
func update(with content: Content) {
    someLabel.text = content.textProperty
}
```

Note: I want to achieve this without reloading table or single section. I want to update only single label in my custom table section view.

I expect the label text to be changed on updateMethod call, but it doesn't happen. What could be the problem?

Edit:

When I scroll section header to top and let it go back down, then it works well.

Comment: as far as i know, you need to update the specific section.

Comment: I want to achieve this without updating the section, as I have already mentioned.

Comment: to do it without updating section or row you should write a delegate method which will be called when a the desired object is updated, and inside the definition of that delegate func you write the code to change specific label's text.

Comment: do you have more than one sections? is updateMethod a class level closure?

Comment: seems like your code is not what you really use, because tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:) does not return any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index of the section you want to change the header of like this:

```
if let headerView = self.tableView.headerView(forSection: <section number>) as? InfoHeaderView {
    headerView.update(with: content)
}
```

But probably for this method to work, your header view should be of type which is subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

Comment: That's what fixed the problem I had. Thanx.